# ISO_1 to UTF8 failed

Tags: mysql, utf-8, character, encode, iso-8859-1

I have a datafile encoding by iso_1, and I changed it to UTF8:

```
file -i test.txt:
... text/plain; charset=utf-8
```

and mysql character_set is:

```
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

My question is:
Why the chinese character is still messy code?

```
ºâÑô...
```

Comment: What is the relationship between the file, the database, ISO_1 (which does not exist, tags say you probably meant ISO 8859-1), chinese characters and messy code? How do you store your data to the database, how do you read it, how do you print it?

Comment: ISO-8859-1, sybase character_set is iso-8859-1, export data to a file, and i need to import data from this file to mysql. I used file -i to get the charset, and I read data by cat ...| head -n

Comment: You can't have Chinese characters in ISO 8859-1. If you stored Chinese characters in UTF-8 while pretending it's ISO 8859-1, your `file -i` would likely detect it as UTF-8, if the proportion of the Chinese characters was high enough. So I'm not sure what you actually have in your file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

THANKS guys，I find use gb18030 covered to utf-8 worked. 
But I dont know why the `file -i` showed the file charset is iso-8859-1.

Answer (score 1):

Which of these were you expecting?

```
                                     big5   6  2 '算栠'
                              gb2312, gbk   6  2 '衡阳'
                            eucjpms, ujis   6  2 '財剩'
```

`ºâÑô` is "Mojibake" for one of those.  See [Trouble with UTF-8 characters; what I see is not what I stored](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38363566/trouble-with-utf8-characters-what-i-see-is-not-what-i-stored)

Some of the `character_set_*` settings reference the encoding *in the client*.  It is quite OK for a column to be `utf8mb4` while the client is using `big5` or `gb2312` (etc), but you must do `SET NAMES big5` or the equivalent.